About Jito-solana validator as RPC Node
I want to run jito-solana validator on mainnet.
But I can't know how to start it.
Please let me know how to start rpc node.
There is no problem on devnet.

Hey there this link might help :
https://www.jito.network/blog/solana-validator-101-getting-started-with-solana-staking/
